# Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab not working in any Application

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 16.10

I have Ubuntu 16.10 running Gnome DE. No application will let me switch tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I've tried it in Google Chrome, Webstorm, Sublime etc.

Nothing seems to be helping and it's so annoying. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is working and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is working well with all other shortcuts.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, and I am completely unsure of what the cause could be

Comment: I've noticed that after booting up, If I wait for a while doing nothing. The issue disappears.

Comment: Does Ctrl-PageDown/Up work?